# Excel - Select end of column + additional rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a macro that selects certain data in my sheet. I have a sheet with data that is pulled into it using:

```
Windows("Item checkout workbook_New.xlsx").Activate
Range("A2:G300").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("VLookup test.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A2:G2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:G300").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Once this data is input, I have two columns `H2:H300` and `I2:I300` that has formulas already in it for Vlookup that get information from `A2:G300`.

What I then need to do is select only the relevant data and copy it back to `Windows("Item checkout workbook_New.xlsx")`. By relevant data, I need to select only cells with data in the `A2:G300` range as well as the `H2:I300` cells that match. Seeing as ALL `H2:I300` cells have data, I am not sure how to do this. I tried to create a macro that uses END to select all of column A and then the rows that go with it, but this is what I got and as you can see it will not work:

```
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range("A2:I78").Select
Selection.Copy
```

I am not great at VBA thus it is hard to come up with things on the fly, but I feel like there should be a way to get this to work. Any advice would be great!

Comment: If you figured out an answer to your question, you can post it as answer instead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Item checkout workbook_New.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Based off your own answer, it seems I may have misinterpreted your question. What I gathered was that you were looking for a way to select relevant cells in a worksheet. The relevant cells could belong to one of two ranges. In one range, cells that are not empty should be selected. In the other range, cells that match a value should be selected. (you can just add in your copy/paste code)

I solved that problem below.

```
Sub test()
    'store results here
    Dim result As Range

    setupTest
    'check this range and return items that are not empty
    selectMatchingCells Range("A1:D1"), result
    'check this range and return items that match value
    selectMatchingCells Range("B2:C4"), result, "hi"
    result.Select
End Sub

Function setupTest()
    Range("A1").Value = "anything"
    Range("c1").Value = "may go"
    Range("D1").Value = "here"
    Range("B2").Value = "hi"
    Range("B3").Value = "but not here"
End Function

Function selectMatchingCells(search As Range, result As Range, Optional searchValue As String = "")
    For Each cell In search
        'are we checking that cell value matches string, or if cell has a value at all?
        If searchValue = vbNullString Then
            'check if cell is not empty
            If IsEmpty(cell) = False Then selectCell result, cell
        Else
            'check if value matches
            If cell.Text = searchValue Then selectCell result, cell
        End If
    Next cell
End Function

Function selectCell(result As Range, cell As Variant)
    'check if result range already exists or not
    If result Is Nothing Then
        'make range equal to cell
        Set result = cell
    Else
        'add cell to existing range
        Set result = Union(result, cell)
    End If
End Function
```

Please be more clear to avoid miscommunication, thanks!